# Chrome issue - jQuery SmoothDivScroll

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I'm having problems getting the SmoothDivScroll plugin to work with Google Chrome. It works fine in FF and IE7 and above though. I've tried playing with the CSS, but no result.

The plugin is this one http://www.maaki.com/thomas/SmoothDivScroll/

<strike>I've put a sample page on my server at</strike>

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem comes from `scrollableArea` width (0px in my chrome DOM inspector). The plugin should set this width enough to encompass all children elements.

With pure css just can just set a huge width so no breaklines will be needed.

Comment: Ah, thats sorted it. Chrome mustn't have been calculating the width of the images... I set the image width in the HTML and its working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ^^ You must wait "load" event of the images to get their dimensions, DOMContentLoaded is too early. I think this was the real problem.

Answer (score 5):

No need to manually set the width. 
Just change this:

```
$(function(){
```

to:

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

That way, it only runs once EVERYTHING (including the images) has been loaded.